# Im trying to create an object using JQuery UI Autocomplete, following the example given, however its currently not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I've tried to copy the example for jQuery UI with my code, however the autocomplete isn't showing currently.

The example is from here:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

```
<input id="FeatureSearch" tabindex="1" class="form-control" @*id="child-name"*@ placeholder="" required="" aria-required="true" type="text" style="width:420px;float:right"><br />
                    @*<input id="autoComplete" tabindex="1">*@    <!-- Default "id" value = "autoComplete"> -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="search-id">
                    <p id="parent-name"></p>
                    <input type="hidden" id="parent-id">    


$(function () {
        var ProductFeatures = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllFeatureNames))/*Json.Encode(*/@*'@Model.AllFeatureNames'*@;
     
        $("#FeatureSearch").autocomplete({
            source: ProductFeatures,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#FeatureSearch").val(ui.item.Name);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#FeatureSearch").val(ui.item.Name);
                $("#search-id").val(ui.item.Id);
                if (ui.item.ParentId != null) {
                    $("#parent-name").val(ui.item.ParentName);
                    $("#parent-id").val(ui.item.ParentId);
                }
                return false;
            },
            appendTo: "#searchbox",
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
                .append("<div>" + item.Name + "<br>" + item.ParentName + "</div>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
```

Comment: I see `@Html.Raw` and similar references in your code - is this all within a view (a .cshtml or .vbhtml page)?

Comment: Yeah it’s within a view(.cshtml). I had it working with a list of strings, but I changed it up to use an object and tried to follow the example on jquery UI but it stopped working

Comment: When looking at the rendered page, do you see something like `var ProductFeatures = { "Someproperty": "some value" }` in the page? What errors, if any, show up in the developer console?

Comment: No errors are showing in the console. The array of objects ProductFeatures shows fine. I previously had this  object working when I used the ProductFeatures.Names for String array version of Jquery UI autocomplete.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example of `ProductFeatures`. Or please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example